# How can I push to an array (in Vue 3)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array and I would like to push some data to it.

```
this.myArray.push(['a' => 'b']);
```

Unfortunately this does not work with Vue 3 as `myArray` appears to be wrapped in a proxy object.

Does anyone know how to push to an array in Vue 3?

Comment: That snippet doesn’t look like valid JavaScript code. What’s `['a' => 'b']` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 37):

It depends how you define the array

### Using `reactive`:

```js
const myArray = reactive([1,2,3])

myArray.push(4); // push works as normal
```

### Using `ref`:

```js
const myArray = ref([1,2,3]);

myArray.value.push(4); // With a `ref` you need to use `value`
```

*Other issues:*

Your syntax is incorrect for what's being pushed, maybe you want:

```js
myArray.push({ a: 'b' });
```

Also, keep in mind there is no component `this` access in the Vue 3 composition API.

Comment: What if the array was in an object like const a = ref({c:[]}), how would we push something into c ?

Comment: @HaadNadeem `a.value.c.push(1)`.  Since `a` is a `ref`, you use `value`.  Since `c` is not a `ref`, you don't.